# How can I move an developed app to another Google account?

Tags: android, apk

I've created and uploaded an Android application but I want to move it to another account. Is it possible? I've searched about it but I haven't found anything.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, just follow these instructions:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626?hl=en

If you would like to change the Google account that you use to publish your applications, you can do so. We will be able to transfer applications to a new account. When applications are transferred, all ratings, comments, metrics, and users will be preserved. To change the Google account associated to your Google Play Developer Console account:

1. Create a new Google Play Developer Console account and pay the $25 registration fee. Please note that we cannot transfer applications until the new account has been created and the registration fee has been purchased. We are able to cancel your original account and refund the registration fee. Additionally, you'll need to change the developer name of your original account slightly if you would like to re-use the name with your new account.
2. Next, contact us from both the original email address and the new email address requesting to transfer applications. We require emails from both accounts so that we can confirm ownership.
3. Once we receive an email from both accounts, the Google Play support team will transfer your applications, and then close your old Developer Console account. Once the refund is processed, you will no longer be able to sign in to Google Play Developer Console with the previous account.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer your application - checklist by Google: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213